# Updating Multiple Select Boxes dynamically

Tags: javascript, html-select

I have a page that has 2-300 select dropdown boxes. I need to dynamically update each one to have the same list of options. Each time I try to update it it only does the first one. I suspect the problem is its not looping through it.

// HTML

```
<form id="myForm">
<select id="selectNumber">
<option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
</form>
<form id="myForm">
<select id="selectNumber">
<option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
</form>
<form id="myForm">
<select id="selectNumber">
<option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
</form>
```

// JavaScript

```
    var myArray = new Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");


    // Get dropdown element from DOM
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("selectNumber");

    // Loop through the array
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
        // Append the element to the end of Array list
        dropdown[dropdown.length] = new Option(myArray[i], myArray[i]);
      }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p6eqrxn8/1/

Comment: You can't give multiple elements the same ID. That's the whole reason for an ID. Perhaps consider giving them a class. [Here's a pretty good article explaining the difference.](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Comment: I see this question two weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Mike said, you can't use the same ID field for all your selects.

"An ID should be unique within a page. However, if more than one element with the specified ID exists, the getElementById() method returns the first element in the source code."

You could try setting the same class to your selects and then use getElementsByClassName(class), which returns all the elements with that class.

Also, if there is no other select element in your page aside from the ones you want to change you could use getElementsByTagName('select') which returns all the select elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getElementById` for your form id and save it to some variable

as in below code then use that variable with `getElementsByTagName`

to get all your `dropdown` of your form.

I modified your html, see below and use this script

```js
        window.onload = function() {
          var myFormdropdown = document.getElementById("myForm");
          var varselect = myFormdropdown.getElementsByTagName("select");
          var myArray = new Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
          
          // Loop through the array
          for (var j = 0; j < varselect.length; j++) {
            for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
              // Append the element to the end of Array list                    
              var option = document.createElement('option');
              option.value = myArray[i];
              option.innerHTML = myArray[i];
              varselect[j].options.add(option);
            }
          }
        };
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
  </select>
  <select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
  </select>
  <select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Hope this will help you.